# При конвертации даты и использование timezone получаю неверный пояс. datetime

Tags: python, datetime

На сервере время -3 по мск, мне нужно чтобы при конвертации времени, оно было московское, сейчас в ручную делаю offset, можно ли использовать для этого datetime timezone, но вот он выдает мне не верный часовой пояс при конвертации. Т.е даже не так, при datetime.now() часовой пояс верный, а вот при конвертации нет

```
>>> tm = datetime.datetime.strptime('29.09.2022', '%d.%m.%Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
>>> tm.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=9000)
>>> tm = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
>>> tm.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте провести локализацию времени,  [как рекомендуют разработчики pytz](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

ваш код:

```
tm = datetime.datetime.strptime('29.09.2022', '%d.%m.%Y').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
print(tm.utcoffset())
```

> 2:30:00

с локализацией:

```
tm = datetime.datetime.strptime('29.09.2022', '%d.%m.%Y').astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
print(tm.utcoffset())
```

> 3:00:00

Comment: Вы оказались правы на счёт локализации, но нужна была не такая, такая даже так выводила не верное время.

Comment: from pytz import timezone -> tz = timezone('Europe/Moscow') -> tz.localize(datetime.strptime('29.09.2022', '%d.%m.%Y')) -> datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSK+3:00:00 STD>)... Решение оказалось в самом верху документации